# Vagrant port forwarding on windows 10

Tags: vagrant, bottle, portforwarding

I've got the following issue with vagrant port forwarding:

I've installed vagrant on my Windows 10 laptop with the box "hashicorp/precise64", created ssh private key to log in from putty and successfully logged in via SSH with the settings :

IP address 127.0.0.1
Port 2222

That makes me think that port forwarding is working for SSH. In the Vagrantfile I've configured the following lines:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8181,
    auto_correct: true
```

On the virtual machine I've installed pip, and with pip I've installed bottle framework:

```
sudo pip install bottle
```

Then I've created a simple bottle script test.py of a hello world page:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=80)
```

and then ran this script with

```
sudo python test.py
```

It started successfully, and when I logged in a different SSH session and used curl to test it, I get normal response on the 80 port.

But when I try to access this script from my host Windows machine I get an error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome and page is not working.

I've aready tried to turn off my firewall on Windows 10 - didn't help. What can be the cause of this trouble?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, thank to one friend of mine.

It turned out that port forwarding works fine, but the problem is in the script itself. The key point here is the following string in the test.py:

```
run(host='localhost', port=80)
```

By this we set up bottle to listen to requests from the localhost, but vagrant sends all requests from a Windows machine as the external ones for the Ubuntu machine.

So, one way to fix the problem (the rough one) would be just setting the following command, instead of the previous one:

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Then all should work properly.